# I am "adjective" and I am "present continuous" in one sentence

Tags: conjunctions, compound-sentences

Do I need to use "I am" twice in one sentence, or it is enough to use it only in the beginning? Where does this rule come from?

My example:

> I am fluent in three languages and I am pursuing the XXX designation.

OR

> I am fluent in three languages and pursuing the XXX designation.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/19211/2303 and http://english.stackexchange.com/q/34045/2303

Comment: With your second iteration you are of course giving double duty to the auxiliary verb _am_, linking it in each case to an object. The problem is that the two objects are of a disparate sort. The first, fluent, is a predicate adjective, whilst the second, pursuing, is a present participle. And though I am confident they're not _supposed_ to be mixed in this way, apprehending a definitive rule for something so nuanced may not be so easy. Perhaps merely these distinctions will aid you in your research. But I think most people would say that such a construction conveys what's intended just fine.

Comment: That is a great point, Tom, you should turn it into an answer.

Comment: Still catching on here a bit. A simple copy and paste yeah, or some built-in means by which to accomplish such a conversion? Oh, and thanks.

Comment: Borrowing a leaf from a fellow mod and a linguist, "Coordination of unlike constituents is known as *syllepsis*, and happens when the coordinated constituents are not parallel in meaning or in grammar." See [Ellipsis that results in one word serving as both subject and object](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2825/ellipsis-that-results-in-one-word-serving-as-both-subject-and-object).

Comment: Copy and paste, @TomRaywood

Comment: I AM ADJECTIVE! Sounds like a shout of triumph.

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest:

> I am fluent in three languages and am pursuing the XXX designation.

because the person "I" is clear, but the "am" is needed to clarify that you are pursuing - is it at of the verb structure, I think.

Answer (score 3):

If you use only one "am", you are committing [syllepsis](http://grammar.about.com/od/rs/g/syllepsisterm.htm), forcing a single word to do unexpected double duty within the sentence, in this case first as a linking verb and second as part of the present participle construction.

As @Schroedingers Cat points out, the best way to resolve this is to repeat the "am" but leave the "I" off, as a fairly standard parallel construction.

(See [this link](http://writebadlywell.blogspot.com/2009/11/learn-about-syllepsis-then-refuse-to.html) for many fine examples of syllepsis.)